# Iterate a list based on the elements of another in python

Tags: python, iteration

There's a lot of answer about iteration but I didn't find what I wanted.
So here is the situation:
I have 2 list of 2 different length. But l1 can only be <= l2

```
l1 = [2, 3, 1, 2, 2]
l2 = [12, 4, 5, 2, 9, 33, 5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 7, 3]
l3 = []
```

I want to write a function which return:

```
l3 = [(l2[0] + l2[1], l2[2] + l2[3] + l2[4], l2[5], l3[6] + l3[7]...)]
```

So

```
if l1[0] == 2:
Add the value of the sum of (the 2 first values of l2) in l3
if l1[0] == 3:
Add the value of the sum of (the next 3 values of l2) in l3
```

I tried:

```
i = 0
for v in l1:
    for k in l2:
        sum(l2[i])
    i += 1
```

But yeah it doesn't work..
thank you !

Comment: You've got some weird parentheses in your initialisation, might want to check for typos there for a start. Next you need  `==` and not `=` for comparison. Finally, it's not clear what you're trying to do at all. You even used elements of `l3` to initialize `l3` which makes no sense.

Comment: How does `l2` relate to `l1`? In your final `l3` it seems like it is just using the pairs of indices `(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), etc` from `l2`, but then you are saying that it depends on the values in `l1`?

Comment: so yes sorry I edit my post. Is it understandable now? I hope so.

Comment: @Waterploof check my answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l1 = [2, 3, 1, 2, 2]
l2 = [12, 4, 5, 2, 9, 33, 5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 7, 3]
l3 = []

assert (len(l2) >= sum(l1))

i = 0
for e in l1:
    l3.append(sum(l2[i:i+e]))
    i += e

print (l3)
# [16, 16, 33, 13, 9]
```